# MySQL ifnull equivalent for php

Tags: php

My scenario:

```
$exTime = get_cfg_var("session.gc_maxlifetime")?get_cfg_var("session.gc_maxlifetime"):1440;
```

I'd like it to be like mysql:

```
$exTime = isnull(get_cfg_var("session.gc_maxlifetime"),1440);
```

or something like it that would also test for FALSE ideally.  That way I'd only have to call the function once!

I know I could just assign it to a var, but that would add another line to my code (oh nooes!!).  It's really a cosmetic thing, I think it'd be easier to read.  Anyway google hasn't helped me (inb4 someone proving me wrong).  Thanks!

Comment: @andre yeah... I'm aware that I could write a function to do it, I'm really trying to find out if there is some built-in way that I don't know about.

It sounds like the answer is "no" but I'm going to hold out a bit.  There was a time when I didn't know about concise if, so I figured hey, maybe this is built in too!  Thanks though.

Comment: I rolled back to remove "mysql" tag.  This question doesn't have to do with mysql, just wanted a bit of php functionality *like* a bit of mysql functionality.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of PHP 5.3 you could also use the [short ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
$exTime = get_cfg_var("session.gc_maxlifetime") ?: 1440;
```

This is basically your anticipated functionality but without having to declare the function. In PHP versions prior to 5.3, you should go with André's answer.

Keep in mind though, that calling the function might throw warnings, if it is about to check arrays in which keys aren't specified:

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 100
    )
);

$example = isNull($array[0][1], 200);
```

Comment: Won't this assign TRUE to $exTime if session.gc_maxlifetime is set?  This doesn't really do it for me, because I need $exTime to hold the return value of get_cfg_var("session.gc_maxlifetime") *unless it's null/false*, not to hold TRUE or 1440. (I assume that that "isnull" is really "is_null" and you aren't using the function from andré).  Thanks though, I didn't know about short ternary!

Comment: wait a second, just remove the "isnull" wrapper and that's the ticket! Thanks!
http://www.asgrim.com/2009/06/30/awesome-short-ternary-operators/

Comment: Just for completeness, here's a link to the PHP docs, where the short ternary operator is mentioned: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Answer (score 3):

How about adding this small function?

```
function isnull($var, $default=null) {
    return is_null($var) ? $default : $var;
}
```

I don't know of any function that does what you want, but since it's not *that* hard to implement you might as well do that if you use it a lot.

Comment: you still can have "Undefined variable" error in this case.